# Unable to Sync Task from sharepoint 2013 to outlook

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, outlook, exchange-server

I have created a team site which has all the app's like document library, asset library, contacts, picture library, issue tracking, and tasks.

I click on connect to outlook and every app gets successfully connected to outlook other than the Tasks lists.

When clicking on "Connect to Outlook" from the tasks list, an error pops up saying "Sorry, Something went wrong, an unexpected error has occurred".

Version of SharePoint- SharePoint 2013 Enterprise
Version of Outlook - Outlook 2010.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Is there a correlation ID with the error?  If so you should post the message from the ULS log.  If no - I would still review ULS, but also the app log in event viewer on your server.